# useOptimizedDrawing alternatives?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nswindow

[useOptimizedDrawing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/useOptimizedDrawing:) is deprecated after 10.10. What are the alternatives for achieving same behaviour? Thanks for help.